# How to access spark and glueContext in Glue Custom Visual Transform script

Tags: aws-glue

I am trying to create a AWS Glue Custom Visual Traform script that can truncate a MySQL table before loading the data into it.

But I am not able to access the spark and glueContext variable from the main job script.
If I am importing again in my custom script it is saying "can not run more than one spark session at once".

This is my custom visual tranform py file.

```py
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

def truncate_mysql_table(self, database_name, table_name, connection_name):
    
    sql = f"TRUNCATE TABLE {database_name.strip()}.{table_name.strip()}"
    data = spark.sql(sql)
    conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf(connection_name)
    data.write \
        .mode('overwrite') \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", conf['url']) \
        .option("database", 'Pacvue_Commerce') \
        .option("dbtable", "dbo.glue_1") \
        .option("user", conf['user']) \
        .option('truncate', 'true') \
        .option("password", conf['password']) \
        .save()

    # print("Table Truncated")
    return self.filter(lambda row: row['age'] == '21')

DynamicFrame.truncate_mysql_table = truncate_mysql_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, I believe this is not possible to pass spark context to the custom visual transform

To pass spark in the parameters of the function `truncate_mysql_table(self, database_name, table_name, connection_name, spark)`,but for that the JSON that needs to specify types and these are the only valid types - 'str' | 'int' | 'float' | 'list' | 'bool'.

I would rather use another custom Glue job (without visual) to TRUNCATE the table needed instead of using a visual job with custom transform for that.
example:

```
# Create a new Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Truncate MySQL Table").getOrCreate()


sql = f"TRUNCATE TABLE {database_name.strip()}.{table_name.strip()}"
data = spark.sql(sql)
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/custom-visual-transform-example-scripts.html & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/custom-visual-transform-json-config-file.html

Comment: Thanks Ananth but I want to accomplish this using Custom Visual Transform only and I achieved this using this script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245824/glue-custom-visual-script-running-indefinitely